# Python write in the same line of file

Tags: python, file, loops

Supose i have a function like this:

```
f=open('file.txt','w')
n=0
while(n<20):
    f.write(n)
    n=n+1
f.close()
```

but the loop writes all numbers to the file, and i just want the current number in the loop

example:

```
1234567891011121314151617181920
```

Comment: Post your actual code. This example code won't run at all.

Comment: what does it mean, "i just want the current number in the loop"?

Comment: `n++` is not valid Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for n in range(20):
        f.write(str(n) + '\n')
```

alternatively:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for n in range(20):
        print(n, file=f)
```

Comment: I think mijailr is wanting the values all on the same line. If so, remove the '\n', and your answer will be perfect.

Comment: @Vortico  doesn't OP want them **not** all in one line?